# Como programar um conversor de unidade celcius para kelvin? (HTML, Javascript) esse codigo fonte não funcionou, seria K = C + 273

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="valor1">Celcius <strong>1</strong>:</label>
<input type="text" name="valor1" id="valor1" />
<label for="res">Kelvin:</label>
      <input type="text" name="res" id="res" />
<input type="button" value="Calcular" class="botao" onClick="calcular(document.calcform.oper.value)"/>
</body>
</html>

javascript function calcular(oper) {
var kelvin = 273;
var valor1 = document.calcform.valor1.value;
var res = valor1 + kelvin;
console.log(res);
  document.calcform.res.value = res;
      }
```

Comment: Vc usa `document.calcform` no JavaScript, mas no HTML não tem nenhum calcform...

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Como o hkotsubo mencionou, o document.calcform não existe. Para acessar um elemento do seu document, entre outras estratégias, vc tem o [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), assim com isso vc acessa o input e pode manipular o valor da forma que quiser/precisar no seu código.

Outro ponto desse problema é a transformação para inteiro, se vc não fizer isso antes da soma, somará uma string (valor do input) com 273, resultando em por exemplo: '123' + 273 = '123273'

```html
<html> 
  <body>
    <script>
      function calcular() {
        var kelvin = 273;
        var valor1 = document.getElementById('valor1').value;
        var res = parseInt(valor1) + kelvin;
        document.getElementById('res').value = res;
      }   
    </script>
    <label for="valor1">Celcius <strong>1</strong>:</label>
    <input type="text" name="valor1" id="valor1" />
    <label for="res">Kelvin:</label>
    <input type="text" name="res" id="res" />
    <input type="button" value="Calcular" class="botao" onClick="calcular()"/>
  </body>
</html>
```